# Moving an already asked rsync question from SU to SF

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question about rsync](https://superuser.com/questions/815237/preserving-existing-destination-symlinks-with-rsync) over on SuperUser, and so far it's gotten little attention and no response.  Before I ask to have it moved over here, I thought I'd ask if it would seem to be a good fit for ServerFault.

I am trying to sync a distribution repository on a server with limited resources, so it's definitely a server related issue for me. I'm hoping that the community agrees. I have 120 workstations connecting to this server for updates (saving many large volume external downloads.)

If ServerFault is the wrong venue, any advice on what the right one would be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question seems fine for Server Fault.

Comment: Thanks.  I've flagged it for migration.